# How to get the duration of Soundpool

Tags: android, soundpool

i am using soundpool to play audio files and my objective is to play a audio file and after finishing, play another audio file.

Here is my code

```
String source_path = "/sdcard/varun/audio.mp3";



mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                int status) {
                            loaded = true;
                        }
                    });
                    sound1  = mSoundPool.load(source_path, 1);

                    hand1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (loaded) {
                                mSoundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1, 1, time - 1, 1);
                                System.out.println("playing=== a");
                            }
                        }
                    }, 21000);
```

Here i am hardcoding the values as 21000 but i need to get the duration of audio file because duration changes with each file.I am working on android 2.2

How to acheive this please help?

Answer (score 3):

try to use this code dude..

```
String[] fileNames = ...
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
for (String fileName : fileNames) {
    AssetFileDescriptor d = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
    mp.reset();
    mp.setDataSource(d.getFileDescriptor(), d.getStartOffset(), d.getLength());
    mp.prepare();
    int duration = mp.getDuration();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: hey i dont want to use mediaplyer i want to use soundpool

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I think we might need to give up on SoundPool :(

Answer (score 3):

While it seems inefficient, you could create a `MediaPlayer` with your desired sound, and then use the `myMediaPlayer.getDuration()` method to give you the milliseconds in the clip.

You can then call `myMediaPlayer.release()` to get rid of any undesired memory footprint. While doing more research I found that I was not the only one to come to this conclusion. This  library:

[Get Duration Of Sound](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/GetDurationOfSound.htm)

uses this exact method to solve the problem. I assume it is a legitimate way to do it, because this guy looks pretty legit.